# How do I fix a broken Folder View

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

The issue I am having is, somehow, my windows explorer has decided to save the **Folder View** for the problematic folders in question with **the same Detail Columns as the General Items preset**, **despite the folder actually being set as for Music** (which is what I want the Folder View to be).

I don't know how this happened. I only noticed it after I moved the audio files into the problematic folders in question, and no matter what I do, **I can't seem to have the folders properly set the view for music - since it's already set as Music**.

The only way I can fix it, is by renaming the folder to something else, **however if I rename it back to its original intended name, the issue persists**.

**It seems that the issue is actually that the folder's Detail Columns are not being set upon changing its Folder View preset. I can set the Detail Columns manually, however once I re-enter the folder, my set Detail Columns are over-written back to the General Items Detail Columns.**

**How can I remove the Folder View data specifically for the problematic folders in question, so they can re-adjust to the proper view**?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by resetting Folder Options from **Tools > Folder Options > View > Reset Folders**